# access attribute via serializer django

Tags: python, django

I got following models:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    ordered_amount = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="order_items"
    )

class Order(models.Model):
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    purchase_order = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
```

I'm now writing a serializer for listing orders. In this OrderSerializer I need to access amount and ordered_amount in the OrderItem class. How do I do this?
This is What I have now:

```
class AdminOrderListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    amount = serializers.IntegerField()
    ordered_amount = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = [
            "purchase_order",
            "reference",
            "amount",
            "ordered_amount",
        ]

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def validate_amount(self, order):
        if order.order_items.amount:
            return order.order_items.amount
        return

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def validate_ordered_amount(self, order):
        if order.order_items.ordered_amount:
            return order.order_items.ordered_amount
        return
```

This gives me following error:

AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `amount` on serializer `AdminOrderItemListSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Order` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Order' object has no attribute 'amount'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to that, one of them is [**`SerializerMethodField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class AdminOrderListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    amount = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    ordered_amount = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_amount(self,obj):
        return obj.order_items.aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))['sum']


    def get_ordered_amount(self,obj):
        return obj.order_items.aggregate(sum=Sum('order_amount'))['sum']
```

### Optimized solution

Another way of achieving this is to [**`annotate`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/) the data to queryset, and access them in serializer. For that, you need to change in view:

```
class SomeView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.annotate(amount=Sum('order_items__amount'),order_amount=Sum('order_items__order_amount'))
```

This is a optimized solution because it reduces database hits(it only hits once).

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! You edited the serializer for the optimized solution. Was it incorrect?

Comment: It wasn't incorrect, rather unnecessary. You actually don't need the source attribute(which I had written and later deleted) to access annotated value if the name of the field matches annotated key. You can use the serializer which you have written.